# Using the same function in identical, dynamically created forms

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm a newbie, trying to build a survey where the user can add up to 5 questions and, within those questions, add 2 - 8 answers.
My problem is that the functions for adding and removing answers work only for the first form.
The forms / questions added dynamically do not work with this function.

I've been looking for a solution with the 'this' keyword, but can't really get my head around it.

If anyone could tell me the keywords to look up, I would be grateful.

```js
(function() {

  var count = 0;

  $('#add_more_questions').click(function() {

    var n = $("form").length;

    if (n < 5) {
      var indsaet = $('hr:last');
      var source = $('form:last'),
        clone = source.clone();

      clone.find(':input').attr('id', function(i, val) {
        return val + count;
      });

      clone.insertBefore(indsaet);

      count++;

    } else {
      $('#add_more_questions').remove();
      alert("Maximum of 5 questions!");

    }
  });
})();



var survey_options = document.getElementById('survey_options');
var add_more_fields = document.getElementById('add_more_fields');
var remove_fields = document.getElementById('remove_fields');
var spm = document.getElementById('spm');
var newq = document.getElementsByClassName('newq');

add_more_fields.onclick = function() {
  var svarNr = survey_options.getElementsByTagName('input');
  if (svarNr.length >= 8) {
    alert("Maximum 8 of answer options");
  } else {
    var newField = document.createElement('input');
    newField.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    newField.setAttribute('name', 'survey_options[]');
    newField.setAttribute('id', 'svar' + (svarNr.length + 1));
    newField.setAttribute('class', 'survey_options');
    newField.setAttribute('size', 50);
    newField.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Answer ' + (svarNr.length + 1));
    survey_options.appendChild(newField);
  }
}

remove_fields.onclick = function() {
  var input_tags = survey_options.getElementsByTagName('input');
  if (input_tags.length >= 3) {
    survey_options.removeChild(input_tags[(input_tags.length) - 1]);
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost:wght@100;300;400;700&display=swap');

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  background-color: #a09db6;
  font-family: 'Jost', sans-serif;
  color: #065535;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 40px 0px rgba(47, 47, 47, .1);
}

input[type="text"] {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  background: none;
  width: 274px;
  color: black;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.controls {
  width: 294px;
  margin: 25px auto;
}

#remove_fields {
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.controls a i.fa-minus {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#finish {

  margin-bottom: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #232c3d;
}

h5 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #232c3d;
}

h6 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #232c3d;
}

#add_more_questions {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: right;
}

#footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -400px;
  width: 800px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: yellow;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 40px 0px rgba(47, 47, 47, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<!-- include font awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0380f5286b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Create your own survey</h1>
<form action="/finishpage.html" method="get">
  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="spms">
      <h6>Type in your question</h6>
      <input type="text" name="spm[]" id="spm1" class="spm" size="80" placeholder="Question">

      <div id="survey_options">
        <h6>... and here, type in the answer options (maximum of 8)</h6>
        <input type="text" name="survey_options[]" id="svar1" class="survey_options" size="50" placeholder="Answer 1">
        <input type="text" name="survey_options[]" id="svar2" class="survey_options" size="50" placeholder="Answer 2">
        <input type="text" name="survey_options[]" id="svar3" class="survey_options" size="50" placeholder="Answer 3">
      </div>
      <div class="controls">
        <a href="#/add_more_fields" id="add_more_fields"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add answer</a>
        <a href="#/remove_fields" id="remove_fields"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Remove answer</a>
        <p></p>

        <h6>Multiple answers possible?</h6>

        <label><input type="radio" name="options" value="radio_button_selected" /> Only one</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="options" value="checkbox_selected" /> Multiple answers okay</label>

        <p class="newquest"></p>

      </div>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<div id="footer">
  <a href="#add_more_questions" id="add_more_questions"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add new question?</a>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/markcod/zhwneg72/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a couple of mishaps in your code - JS specifically.

First, don't use IDs when referencing items that occur multiple times. In the first part (the IIFE statement) you're copying the form in which some elements contain an ID attribute - I'm talking about the `add` and `remove answer` buttons. Therefore, you end up having two HTML elements with the same ID value, which apart from being against the W3 standard, creates many complications.

Second, while you copy the elements, you don't copy their event listeners. The elements you're referencing in `add_more_fields.onclick` and `remove_fields.onclick` belong to the first form only.

I've managed to correct this, however, you should replace IDs with classes and find a way to reference them.

Replace your JS code with the one below.

```js
(function () {
  var count = 0;

  $('#add_more_questions').click(function () {
    var n = $('form').length;

    if (n < 5) {
      var indsaet = $('hr:last');
      var source = $('form:last'),
        clone = source.clone();

      console.log(clone[0]);

      clone.find(':input').attr('id', function (i, val) {
        console.log(val, count);
        return val + count;
      });

      clone.insertBefore(indsaet);

      var survey_options = clone[0].querySelector('#survey_options');
      var add_more_fields = clone[0].querySelector('#add_more_fields');
      var remove_fields = clone[0].querySelector('#remove_fields');

      add_more_fields.onclick = function () {
        var svarNr = survey_options.getElementsByTagName('input');
        if (svarNr.length >= 8) {
          alert('Maximum 8 of answer options');
        } else {
          var newField = document.createElement('input');
          newField.setAttribute('type', 'text');
          newField.setAttribute('name', 'survey_options[]');
          newField.setAttribute('id', 'svar' + (svarNr.length + 1));
          newField.setAttribute('class', 'survey_options');
          newField.setAttribute('size', 50);
          newField.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Answer ' + (svarNr.length + 1));
          survey_options.appendChild(newField);
        }
      };

      remove_fields.onclick = function () {
        var input_tags = survey_options.getElementsByTagName('input');
        if (input_tags.length >= 3) {
          survey_options.removeChild(input_tags[input_tags.length - 1]);
        }
      };

      count++;
    } else {
      $('#add_more_questions').remove();
      alert('Maximum of 5 questions!');
    }
  });
})();

var survey_options = document.getElementById('survey_options');
var add_more_fields = document.getElementById('add_more_fields');
var remove_fields = document.getElementById('remove_fields');
var spm = document.getElementById('spm');
var newq = document.getElementsByClassName('newq');

add_more_fields.onclick = function () {
  var svarNr = survey_options.getElementsByTagName('input');
  if (svarNr.length >= 8) {
    alert('Maximum 8 of answer options');
  } else {
    var newField = document.createElement('input');
    newField.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    newField.setAttribute('name', 'survey_options[]');
    newField.setAttribute('id', 'svar' + (svarNr.length + 1));
    newField.setAttribute('class', 'survey_options');
    newField.setAttribute('size', 50);
    newField.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Answer ' + (svarNr.length + 1));
    survey_options.appendChild(newField);
  }
};

remove_fields.onclick = function () {
  var input_tags = survey_options.getElementsByTagName('input');
  if (input_tags.length >= 3) {
    survey_options.removeChild(input_tags[input_tags.length - 1]);
  }
};
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot for your help. Yes, the ID attributes are a bit of a nightmare. Some of them do get updated to a unique id through the function, but not all of them. I have to get rid of those. Thanks so much.